# java insert/update a single column in a table from an array

Tags: java, mysql

how can i insert/update a single column in a table. i want to fill the column from an array values.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PufqM.png)

i only want to insert/update **inGram** table.

i already tried this but not worked:

```
String sql="INSERT INTO total_ingredient (inGram) VALUES('"+subtractIngredent[0]+"',"
        + " '"+subtractIngredent[1]+"','"+subtractIngredent[2]+"',"
        + "'"+subtractIngredent[3]+"','"+subtractIngredent[4]+"',"
        + "'"+subtractIngredent[5]+"','"+subtractIngredent[6]+"', )";
```

thank you.

Comment: You nedd as many inserts as rows you want to insert. Learn repared statements. Your code is hard to read, will break if any value contains a quote, is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, and is less efficient than a solution using a prepared statement. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Answer (score 0):

This should be written as:

```
String sql="INSERT INTO total_ingredient (inGram) VALUES('"+subtractIngredent[0]+"'),"
        + "('"+subtractIngredent[1]+"'),('"+subtractIngredent[2]+"'),"
        + "('"+subtractIngredent[3]+"'),('"+subtractIngredent[4]+"'),"
        + "('"+subtractIngredent[5]+"'),('"+subtractIngredent[6]+"')";
```

To make your code handle an array of any size, you shrould conside using a loop. Like JB Nizer has mentioned, consider using prepared statements than generating the query yourself.

Comment: Then why do you suggest a poor solution not using prepared statements?

Comment: His question is more about inserting multiple rows with one query than it is about utilizing MySQL from a language such as C# or Java. I would have given an example using prepared statements if i knew what language he was using. MySQL can be used from C#, Java, PHP, etc and each of these has its own way of interacting with a database.